# SAP JCo3 table empty

Tags: jco, sapjco3

I am re-writing my JCo2 code to JCo3 code to run on a 64 bit Windows server.  When I try to read my SAP table with the JCo3 code it is returning an empty table. However when I run the JCo2 code I have 2 records in the table.

The result is records = 0. When I run the JCo2 code on the same table the result is records = 2.

Please tell me what I am missing.

Here is a snippet of my JCo3 code:

```java
System.out.print("after try");
try {
    ABAP_AS2 = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(ABAP_MS);
} catch (Exception e) {
    ABAP_AS2 = null;
    System.out.print("ABAP_AS2 = null");
}
ABAP_AS2.ping();
JCoFunction function = ABAP_AS2.getRepository().getFunction("ZPC_RFC_READ_QMLN");
function.execute(ABAP_AS2);
System.out.println("STFC_CONNECTION finished:");
JCoTable return_table = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("DATA");   
Sytem.out.println("get table");
int records = return_table.getRow();
System.out.println(records);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you haven’t read the API documentation:

```
`int getRow()`
Returns the current row number. The first row number is 0, the second is 1, and so on.
```

You probably want to switch to `getNumRows()`.

Comment: Thank you. So I changed the code to getNumRows() and I still get records = 0. When I try to execute the code:  for (int i = 0; i < return_table.getNumRows(); i++) - (which comes directly from the API documentation) it doesn't enter the loop. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you used the remote debugging facility to find out whether the function module recieves and returns the correct values in the first place?

Comment: I don't know your RFC. Are there any import parameters you should have set?
Something like `function.getImportParameterList().setValue("DATUM_VON", datum_von);`
Or is there any return code you can check?

`String rc = function.getExportParameterList().getString("RETURNCODE");`

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.  It seems my problems was with the install of the JCO on the server. :(  My code was not the problem.